# Search Kit with an auto toggle

Tags: drupal-7, searchkit

Wondering how to get the auto search toggle enabled for search kit
Is it a option by default or does it take customization...

here are two images side by side two diff systems both run on drupal 7
[image: With Auto Toggle]

[image: Without auto toggle]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the Auto-run setting that appears on the search *display* edit page (not the compose search page).

Add a display to that search (using the Add dropdown at the left) and then you should see something like this:

[image]

Comment: no, that i'm aware of.
look at the pictures I sent its on the compose screen

Comment: Ok I see what you're showing on an older version (5.40). I think it was moved to the search display, so that's where it is now. A search display, or a form based on it, is what end-users are more likely to be interacting with.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I should have clearly specified the version difference to make your life easier 
appreciate it,